# Adding a close link is jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have implemented jquery multi autocomplete using jquery UI multi autocomplete in my project, which is working fine. But now there is a requirement where I have to add a close(X) link at the top right corner of each option i have selected into the autocomplete textbox. When i will click on a particular selections close link it will remove that particular option.  How should I do it.

Basically it is very much similar to the stackoverflow TAGS autocomplete at the buttom when we are asking a new question.

Comment: You probably can't do that with jQuery's "standard" autocomplete plugin - if you can't find another plugin that does the job, you might want to roll your own. That said, it's possible that you can (re)use some parts of jQuery Autocomplete to get the data for whatever you do, and then do only the customizing of the UI yourself (given of course that licensing allows that, which I know nothing about).

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?